# Jinja2 django 1.6 How to eliminate quotes from include tag?

Tags: django, jinja2

Is this a bug? I have codes in template file like:

```
<div class="row" id="tags">
    {%include 'y.html'%}
</div>
```

then jinja2 will render as:
[image]

But I never have any quotes in my template. And if I directly place codes in y.html in div section, this problem won't happen.

So, If I have to use include tag, How can I eliminate those annoying quotes?

EDIT:

Thanks for Daniel Roseman, the quotes only exist in Chrome tools, not in the actual html code. **BUT:**

If I **use Chrome browser and use include tag**, the layout is abnormal:
[image]

If I **use Chrome browser and don't use include tag** , the layout is OK:
[image]

So, there must be something wrong with jinja2 or chrome.

If it is caused by Jinja2, then how to solve this problem? Thanks.

**EDIT2:**

more strange things: if I move the `<div class="row" id="tags"></div>` into `y.html`, the problem will disappear even if I still use include tag.

This may be the solution, but still I don't why.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't Jinja2 doing anything. This is your just your browser's developer tools. The actual HTML will be fine.

Comment: But it affect the web layout. If a user visit my site with Chrome, the layout doesn't show as I expected. I add the picture at the end of my question.